# Drupal 7 Bugtracker module?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, bug-tracking

I need a Bugtracker / Issuetracker module for Drupal 7. All i've found is [Support Ticketing System](http://drupal.org/project/support). But its a bit buggy, always tells me "You must select a client" (user rights are configured properly, dont ask ;-).

Is there any alternative to it?

Comment: This is the same question as http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15366/bug-issue-tracker-for-drupal-7. There are some more answers to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try the project module and project issue module yet?

http://drupal.org/project/project

http://drupal.org/project/project_issue

Answer (score 0):

In addition to project modules, you can also try Case Tracker module.

https://drupal.org/project/casetracker